# Fortran Matrix Division

Tags: matrix, fortran, fortran90, matrix-inverse, fortran95

I am trying to divide matrices in Fortran(f90). X=R/Z =>
X[6x1], R[6x6] and Z[6x1] are matrices.

Normally in Matlab, You can write that equation and easy but in Fortran little bit different because Fortran has no any division properties so that I need to take the inverse of Z matrix (X=R*Z^-1).

The problem is matrix shape because here Z matrix(6x1) and not square so I cant take the inverse of that. Is there any ready function for the division and How can handle if the inverse of the matrix is not square?

```
program main
implicit none
real, dimension(6,1) :: X
real, dimension(6,6) :: R
real, dimension(6,1) :: Z
real, dimension(6,1) :: Z_inv 

!X=R/Z
call mat_inverse(Z) ! Please ignore inverse part
Z_inv=Z             ! Mat_inverse function is already defined in math 
                    ! Kernel Library but I just call that mat_inverse
                    ! Because I call mat_inverse subroutine
! X=R*Z^-1                     
X=Matmul(R,Z_inv)

end program main
```

Comment: You can calc the one-sided inverse in this case. I'll let you with an link for the wikipedia on that matter, an later when I get home I write a proper answer. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse

Comment: Please use the [tag:fortran] tag for all Fortran questions. **Many** more people will read it then.

Comment: I would advise you to look into the BLAS/LAPACK libraries (netlib.org/lapack). There are more than enough routines for stuff like that and you would probably never get a routine more efficient than the LAPACK counterpart.

Comment: I checked Lapack which has only for nonsigular. May be I didn't see for singular.

Comment: I tried to use `Dgetri` and `Dgetrf` but it didn't worked!

Comment: How did it not work? If the matrix you're inverting isn't square, I think you're kind of out of luck of a standard solution.

Comment: btw, I think even Matlab does a X=R*Z^-1... :) There is no such thing as matrix division per se. Are you sure you even want to do that? What is the goal you want to achieve with that operation?

Comment: Thanks a lot for comments :) I found another approach so that I will not use this transformation.

Comment: @Fl.pf. the matrix info was singular. I was doing in matlab is ok but in fortran no so I am not using anymore this transformation. Thanks a lot :)